# Load Data from heroku to lokal MySQL on Windows7

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, heroku

**I'm trying to download data from heroku to local Win7 MySQL**, using standard syntax as described in [Push and Pull Databases To and From Heroku](https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2009/3/18/push_and_pull_databases_to_and_from_heroku).

I've been doing it several times with sqlite locally but with MySQL Heroku Toolbelt seems to have problems to connect to the database.

I get the following Error:

### Failed to connect to database:

### Sequel::AdapterNotFound -> LoadError: cannot load such file -- mysql

Below you can see my console log. I listed all dependencies as well. (May be I miss one?)

What do I miss here?

---

**Win7 console:**

```
c:\Sites\app>heroku db:pull mysql://root:passwd@localhost/app-staging
Loaded Taps v0.3.24
Warning: Data in the database 'mysql://root:passwd@localhost/app-staging' will be overwritten and will not be
recoverable.

 !    WARNING: Destructive Action
 !    This command will affect the app: app-staging
 !    To proceed, type "app-staging" or re-run this command with --confirm app-staging

> app-staging
Failed to connect to database:
  Sequel::AdapterNotFound -> LoadError: cannot load such file -- mysql

c:\Sites\app>bundle show mysql2
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.11-x86-mingw32

c:\Sites\app>mysql -V
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.11, for Win32 (x86)

c:\Sites\app>heroku --version
heroku/toolbelt/2.40.1 (i386-mingw32) ruby/1.9.3
```

Answer (score 0):

The best possible solution out of this situation is to use a postgres database locally as well, and use `heroku pg:pull`, currently available on the pg-extras plugin (https://github.com/heroku/heroku-pg-extras).

Answer (score 0):

I second hgmnz's recommendation to use PostgreSQL locally, but if you really want to use MySQL via the mysql2 driver, you need to use `mysql2://root:passwd@localhost/app-staging` instead of `mysql://root:passwd@localhost/app-staging`.